# Docx4j HTML <Strong> and underline not working

Tags: java, xhtml, docx4j

I am using Docx4j/ImportXHTML to generate the Word document. But it fails to underline with text.

My HTML is :

```
<h2 style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 19px; text-align: justify;">
   <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff6600;">
   <span style="font-family: 'Helvetica 45 Light';"><strong>My Service Space</strong></span></span>
</h2>
```

This HTML is generated by the TinyMCE editor at frontend. In HTML viewer the underline is there but it's not generated in Doc.

Any suggestion to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<h2 style="font-family: 'Helvetica 45 Light'; font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px; text-align: justify; color: #ff6600;"> <span style="text-decoration: underline;">My Service Space</span> </h2>`

I hope revolve the problem